# How to set positional parameters in parameter sets?

Tags: powershell, f#, positional-parameter, parameter-sets

I wrote a function with four parameters. The first two parameters are mandatory for both sets : `Payload` and `Algorithm`.
The last two parameters (`Secret` and `FilePath`) define the parameter set.
The order of defined paramters is:

1. Payload
2. Algorithm
3. Secret
4. FilePath

I set `Payload` the positional value of 0 and `Algorithm` the value of 1.
As `Secret` and `FilePath` are mutually exclusive I set their value to 2.

```
[<Parameter(
  Position=0,
  Mandatory=true,
  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true)>]
[<ValidateNotNullOrEmpty>]
member val Payload : Hashtable = Hashtable () with get, set
[<Parameter(
  Position=1,
  Mandatory=true,
  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true)>]
member val Algorithm : cryptographyType = { Algorithm = HMAC; Encryption = SHA256 } with get, set
[<Parameter(
  Position=2,
  ParameterSetName="Key",
  Mandatory=true,
  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true)>]
[<ValidateNotNullOrEmpty>]
member val Secret : string = String.Empty with get, set
[<Parameter(
  Position=2,
  ParameterSetName="FilePath",
  Mandatory=true,
  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true)>]
[<ValidateNotNullOrEmpty>]
member val FilePath : System.IO.FileInfo = null with get, set
```

When I run the function using only the positions, I get a file error when I intend to use the `FilePath` parameter because the function probably expects it to be the `Secret` parameter.

Is there a way to use positional parameter for parameter sets?

Comment: "I set... " - please, just post the actual code instead of _descriptions of code_ :)

Comment: without seeing the definition of your `param` block is a bit hard to help

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It's clearly F#, I've updated the tags :)

Answer (score 2):

> When I run the function using only the positions, I get a file error when I intend to use the `FilePath` parameter because the function probably expects it to be the `Secret` parameter.

If you want the `FilePath` parameter set to be the default, set the `DefaultParameterSetName` property on a `Cmdlet` attribute decorator on the containing type:

```
[<Cmdlet("Verb", "Noun", DefaultParameterSetName = "FilePath")>]
type MyCmdlet() =
    ...
```

Comment: that's damn fast lol on fire huh

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon [pew pew](https://media.tenor.com/kqkWO-L3xHgAAAAd/lucky-luke-shadow.gif)

Comment: Hi Mathias,
But then I would have a problem with the `Secret` parameter. Can I interpret your answer that it is not possible to have two mutually exclusive parameters with the same positional value?

Comment: @Alex_P Correct, you can't have 2 defaults, and there's no "magic" available to make PowerShell telepathic at runtime :) It's either 1 or the other

Comment: @Alex_P Think about it for a moment. How in the world should PowerShell "know" that the `relativePath` in `Verb-Noun $payload $algorithm relativePath` is a path and not a literal secret value?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, well I was hoping the parameter sets would allow this bit.
Anyhow, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Alex_P How would that work? What would happen in the example above? FilePath picked because... why?